# SQL Server Express 2012 Repair

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I have a copy of SQL server Express 2012 database which may be corrupt.  When I tried to run a repair on it I was asked for the original installation media.  The Options were for an MSI or ISO image.  However, SQL sever express came as an exe file.
How do I go about repairing an express version ?

Comment: .exe files may also be a self extracting zip files when you install they extract contents into a temp folder. My advice, run that exec file again and see where the contents are extracted.

Comment: if setup is corrupt yu need to download it again. Anyways how you found out it is corrupt ?

Comment: Is the database or the server software corrupt? Is there any error message? When does the error occur/appear?

Answer (score 1):

Run the setup.exe for express again and you can find the option to repair the installation on the from the installation screen instead of doing it through add and remove programs. You can also install [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) and use that to extract the setup file to get the msi files for the repair